# Divide numpy matrix elements in 2-D matrix by sum of all elements in that position of 1-D

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If we have a matrix such as:

[ [ 2, 3 ] , [ 4, 9 ], [ 3, 1 ] ]

I want to know how to be able to divide matrix elements as follows:

Sum the elements in the same position of their respective 1-D vectors

2 + 4 + 3 = 9

3 + 9 + 1 = 13

Then divide each of the elements by the sum corresponding to their position

Desired output:

[ [ .22, .23 ], [ .44, .69 ], [ .33, .08 ] ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One solution:

```
import numpy as np
data = [[2, 3] , [4, 9], [3, 1]]
result = data / np.sum(data, axis=0)
print(result)
```

#### Output:

> [[ 0.22222222  0.23076923] 
>   [ 0.44444444  0.69230769] 
>    [ 0.33333333  0.07692308]]